# SUMIFS style calculation of pandas GroupBy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to divide the result of two columns multiplied with each other, by the aggregate total I get for a groupby, which is based on a SUMIFS style conditions matching.

I groupby as normal

```
df.groupby(["Month","Category","Currency"])["Amount"].sum()
```

How do I honor the values that come out of this groupby and use each respective number as the denomenator of the division of the main dataframe calculation (roughly written below).

```
Month            Category      Currency                    Amount
2000-01-31      Deposit-CA           FC               -8994788.78
                                    GBP             -791962507.93                                 USD               -31808347.06
2001-02-28     Deposit-SA            FC              -10496460.50
                                    KWD            -1064463148.00
2002-08-31      Corporate           KWD                 343753.63
```

For example I want to calculate

```
df["Profit_Rate"]*df["Amount"]/groupby amount sum for each case conditions matching
```

With a SUMIF in excel you are able to provide ranges of data and the conidtion which you would like to text to get a total number that can be used in the calculation.

My question is how to access these totals from a groupby and utilise them as a number in another equation. For example in my case trying to calculate percentage yield based on multiple factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking to transform the sum:

```
totals = df.groupby(["Month","Category","Currency"])["Amount"].transform('sum')
```

Then you can do

```
df["Profit_Rate"] * df["Amount"] / totals
```